# Do filters on forms apply to SQL queries and DLOOKUPs also

Tags: ms-access

I am developing an application which can be used for multiple companies, and multiple business units within each company.  Currently I do not use any filters in form objects.  But I find myself putting in extra time and code into each SQL statement and in many DLOOKUPs that limit data to the current company & business unit that the user is logged into.
Would using filters in each form eliminate the need to include code to do this?

Comment: I failed to mention that my application is an MS Access front-end with all data stored in a MySQL database.

Comment: Using filters on each form would simplify things as far as forms are concerned however you would still need to handle your data selections in any VBA code that uses SQL or DLOOKUP. I would suggest that you set up a function that generates the additional selection for the WHERE clause. You can then call this function in every SQL and DLOOKUP to select the appropriate company/business unit based on the user. With some careful design you could even use this function to set your form filters. The big benefit here is that all your selection code is in one place and easily maintained.

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler to filter on the source. This means, always apply a filter on the tables having the CompanyId field by using a *query as source* for your forms and reports etc., like:

```
Select * From SomeTable Where CompanyId = CurrentCompanyId()
```

This requires a simple function:

```vb
Public Function CurrentCompanyId(Optional CompanyId As Long) As Long

    Static Id As Long

    If CompanyId <> 0 Then
        Id = CompanyId
    End If

    CurrentCompanyId = Id

End Function
```

This allows you to switch between companies instantly:

```vb
CurrentCompanyId SomeOtherCompanyId
```